# Using razor inside a string on view

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to place some Razor stuff inside a link but can't quite get it to register correctly. The part that is going wrong is the `@{ @Url...`

```
<a class="social-icons-anchor" HREF="mailto:?subject=Check out this blah! - Blah&body=@{ @Url.AbsoluteAction(" Details", "Blah" , new { blahID = Model.Blah.BlahID }); }">
```

What's the correct way of placing this kind of link in?

**Edit:**

The outcome seems to be this (Notice the spacing):

```
https://blah-blahdev.azurewebsites.net/blah/ details?blahID=121
```

Here is the method helper I am using:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtension
{
    public static string AbsoluteAction(this UrlHelper url, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null)
    {
        string scheme = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;
        return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the @ 2 times. Just use  @Url.AbsoluteAction() and you'll be fine

Comment: it's doing exactly what you asked: there's a space in your AbsoluteAction call parameter so there's a space in your output URL

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Notice the space you have in the Url.AbsoluteAction(" Details")

Comment: Brofit greenhorn. Thanks mannnnn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to use `Razor` code inside a `Razor` block. To fix this, just remove the `@{`...`}` :

```
<a class="social-icons-anchor" HREF="mailto:?subject=Check out this blah! - Blah&body= @Url.AbsoluteAction(" Details", "Blah" , new { blahID = Model.Blah.BlahID })">
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you must remove the @{}, but.

Create a helper:

```
@helper MailToThing(string email, string body, string title, string subject) {
    <a class="social-icons-anchor" href="mailto:@email?subject=@subject&body=@body">@title</a>
}
```

Then you will have to get the blah,blah thing:

```
@{
 var body = @Url.AbsoluteAction("Details", "Blah" , new { blahID = Model.Blah.BlahID });
 var email = "brahbrahbrah@bbhmm.com";
}
```

And then render:

```
@MailToThing(email, body, "", "Check out this blah! - Blah")
```